# I was wondering if anyone knew of a video player written with vbscript or php that works in IE 8

Tags: php, internet-explorer, video, vbscript

I have been asked to write a video player application for IE 8. IE 8 can not use the video html 5 tag. I also can not get the third party to install flash silver light or any third party application. I have tried video.js with this code

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.8.8/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 -->
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
  poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="fenceflipped.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <object width="640" height="264" data="fenceflipped.mp4"></object>
  </video>

  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.8.8/video.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This does not work just a red x on the upper left. I was wondering if anyone ever did php or classic asp to write a custom video player that could run on IE 8? I could use these technologies but because we do not own the equipment I can not install any third party stuff like flash..... I know this is stupid I asked for chrome and I got denied....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="VBScript">
            Sub RunProgram
    MediaPlayer1.filename="C:\Users\User\Music\Self Esteem - The offspring.mp4"
            End Sub
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload=RunProgram>
<OBJECT CLASSID="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" WIDTH="652"
    HEIGHT="382" ID="MediaPlayer1">
<PARAM NAME="AutoStart" VALUE="1">
<PARAM NAME="Filename" VALUE="C:\Users\User\Music\Self Esteem - The offspring.mp4">
<PARAM NAME="ShowControls" VALUE="0">
</OBJECT>
    </body>
</html>
```

This uses Media Player.

Comment: this worked thank you very much